# SSIS package in SQL Agent fails after a few succesfull runs

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have a ssis package stored in the packagestoredestination that I call from SQL Server Agent.

This package runs after a SQL server service restart in approx 10 minutes.
Next time in an hour and 3th time fails after 4 hours.

What I also notice is that the memory percentage in use of the server is always rising after every run.

The message I receive in the SQL Agent:
Message
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Started:  1:04:13  Finished: 5:45:18  Elapsed:  16864.3 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

I have no clue/idea where to start searching...

Comment: The first thing you want to do is add a catch-all error handler to your SSIS package (if there isn't already) which logs the actual error message somewhere. The error message you are currently getting is just a generic error that doesn't give you the detail of what caused the package to fail. Based on what you describe it's probably some kind of resource problem. However, I can't speculate as to what that might be without more information about what the package is actually doing.

Comment: [SQL Server is designed to acquire and hold onto memory if it needs it](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18881/2131).  [Fast/Slow](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) is likely parameter sniffing but until you provide details, we'll never know. Which version of SQL Server? In the SQL Agent error log, there will be more messages than this. The top level message reports how the job did, expand the node and pull out the detail.